# unable to start billing service

Tags: in-app-purchase

i'm trying to implement in-app billing in my app.
i'm using code from dungeons sample.

everything is working great and i can purchase.
but after i leave the app i get Error "app has stopped working"
and in the LogCat i see.

**05-10 14:33:22.293: E/AndroidRuntime(9568): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service com.package.name.BillingService@2beca0b0 with null: java.lang.NullPointerException**

anybody knows what can cause that problem?

**edit-1:** the problem is that the billingService is still active. and onStart is trying to send null intents (i can solve this by if null==intent ,but it's not the way)
i'm using the unbind when i'm finished purchase.

thanks.

Comment: Do you mean this.unbind() in handleCommand ?